# pyftpdlib import error on windows

Tags: python, ftp, pyftpdlib

I want to set up an ftp server on windows using pyftpdlib when sudenly i get error message.

I want to run this:

```
from pyftpdlib.handlers import FTPHandler
from pyftpdlib.servers import FTPServer
from pyftpdlib.contrib.authorizers import WindowsAuthorizer

authorizer = WindowsAuthorizer()
authorizer = WindowsAuthorizer(anonymous_user="guest", anonymous_password="1234")
handler = FTPHandler
handler.authorizer = authorizer
server = FTPServer(('', 2121), handler)
server.serve_forever()
```

But when i want to import "WindowsAuthorizer" i got this error message:

> from pyftpdlib.contrib.authorizers import WindowsAuthorizer c:\Program
>   Files\Python27\lib\site-packages\pyftpdlib\contrib__init__.py:3: Dep
>   recationWarning: pyftpdlib.contrib namespace is deprecated
>   _depwarn("pyftpdlib.contrib namespace is deprecated") c:\Program Files\Python27\lib\site-packages\pyftpdlib\contrib\authorizers.py:35: 
>   DeprecationWarning: pyftpdlib.contrib.authorizers module is
>   deprecated; use pyf tpdlib.authorizers instead
>   _depwarn("pyftpdlib.contrib.authorizers module is deprecated; "

I really dont know what is the problem, i have had installed pywin32 already.

Comment: it seems to be a warning and not an error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This looks like a warning, not an error

there is print in the code, which says like this

```
_depwarn("pyftpdlib.contrib.authorizers module is deprecated; "
         "use pyftpdlib.authorizers instead")
```

which means this statement should be changed from

```
from pyftpdlib.contrib.authorizers import WindowsAuthorizer
```

to

```
from pyftpdlib.authorizers import WindowsAuthorizer
```